# How to enable secure communication between Docker Containers in a Swarm?

Tags: docker, communication, docker-swarm, pki, man-in-the-middle

I have a question concerning secure communication in a Docker Swarm. 
The Docs mentioned that between manager and worker nodes a PKI is established.  So we have secure communication between two or more Docker Engines.
What about the containers running the tasks in the (worker) nodes?

For example we use two nodes, a manager and a worker node. For simplicity we have one service with one task (one container) on each node.
How can they communicate securely?
Is it right that I have to establish a PKI for containers within the PKI of the engines?
Is there a possibility to avoid this or a best practise to do this?
Is there another way to exchange public keys between containers securely?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think is the same as for a non-Docker scenario - i.e. how to do cert/key distribution across services.